# dynamically resized array based queues in C - are they used in practice?

Tags: c, queue, realloc

I'm working on a self-resizing queue in C using arrays with structs and int pointers.

I wanted to be able to dynamically resize it (double it as needed) using realloc and of course still preserve the priority or "queueness". I'm struggling to do that last part cleanly. I've got it working as a queue of static size, which I know is the most common use of circular buffers, and I can realloc that block. I just can't find the best way to put humpty dumpty back together. I know I can implement a queue easily as a linked list. I just wanted to make a good attempt for learning purposes but I don't see many people asking this particular question.

There was one person who asked about it here with respect to Java, but I don't know that language. So anyway my question is: is there any point or advantage to making queues with arrays if you know you'll have to resize them later? It seems overly complicated and wasteful regarding time and space complexity, so do people always them and just go wtih linked lists or other methods in the field?

Edit: When I say priority above, I'm not referring to priority queues, but general queue FIFO ordering.

Comment: Just use a linked list. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you have problems with code, please show the code. If you don't have problems with code it's probably off-topic.

Comment: Yes, using `realloc` to dynamically expand an array is totally valid. (e.g.) `struct dynarray { int maxcount; int curcount; int *base; }`. Plus the code you probably have. That has many uses. Primarily when you just need to append new entries to the list.

Comment: To put humpty dumpty back together, you'll be better off using `malloc` to double the memory, and one or two `memcpy` to put the existing queue entries at the beginning of the new memory. Then, of course, free the old memory.

Comment: Your issue is [as tadman pointed out] that there is a _better_ way to create a priority queue. Note that you _can_ do it with a dynarray. But, the problem is speed. You'd have to append to the end and then _resort_ based on priority (i.e.) it is slow. When you pop, you have to "slide" the array. A linked list is faster: tranverse the existing list to find the insertion point O(n/2) and link in the new entry. A pop operation is just pull off the head of the list O(1). So, a linked list is the right [better] tool for the ultimate use you have.

Comment: @CraigEstey I think "priority" was intended to mean "order" (as in: preserve the order of the entries in the queue). The fact that OP mentions the use of a circular buffer indicates (to me anyways) that this is a fifo queue, not a priority queue.

Comment: @user3386109 Hmm ... Yes, after rereading the post, that is a valid alternate interpretation [perhaps OP can clarify?]. Now, after reading it a third time, _I'm_ more confused than ever as to what OP has for existing code and what the ultimate objective is.

Comment: @CraigEstey Agreed, seeing OP's existing code would add some much needed clarity.

Comment: `realloc()` is basically just `new = malloc(newsize); memcpy(new, old, min(oldsize, newsize)); free(old)`. If this doesn't fit your needs, it's probably best to do what @user3386109 suggested.

Comment: I didn't share my code because it's messy and I thought it would only confuse, even though I know in general it is best to share. I thought I was clear but I guess I wasn't. I didn't realize that priority had a different meaning with queues so yes user33 is correct. I was working on a FIFO queue using an int pointer (i.e. array). When I realloc'd the data, it threw it out of order so i'd have to find a system to put it back in queue 'priority'- i.e. FIFO, so Craig's answer basically answers my question.